# Generic Sum for Numeric and String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function, which return sum of numbers

```
func sum<T: Numeric>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> T {
    return a + b
}
```

And I need to improve this function so that also return the concatenation of Strings by this function without overloading. I probe use RangeReplaceableCollection, but i can't use this protocol with Numeric protocol.

For example:

```
sum(2, 3) -> 5
sum(1.5, 2.4) -> 3.9
sum("abc", "def") -> "abcdef"
```

Comment: I mean concatenation

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: This is much clearer but why can't you use overloading here? It would make the solution easy to implement

Comment: exactly, just add a new func `func sum(_ a: String, _ b: String) -> String { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have one generic function for such a case you would need to find a common behavior that could be used as a constraint for a generic Type. In your case, you can do (**but you should NOT**) this:

**DON'T DO THIS**

```swift
extension String: AdditiveArithmetic {
    // some stupid placeholders, as there is no obvious behavior for that :D
    public static func - (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String {
        lhs
    }

    public static var zero: String {
        ""
    }
}

func sum<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> T {
    a + b
}

print(sum("LOl", "KEK")) // LOLKEK
print(sum(1, 2)) // 3
```

I would **RECOMMEND** just to add a new func for that particular case

```swift
func sum(_ a: String, _ b: String) -> String {
    a + b
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protocol AddProtocol {


static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

func add<T: AddProtocol>(num1: T, _ num2: T) -> T {
return num1 +  num2
}
```

extension Int: AddProtocol {
}

extension String: AddProtocol {}

```
print(add(num1: "Abc", "Xyz"))

print(add(num1: 12, 30))
```